# I would like to know the details of "Data Index Pricing" in the EnterpriseSearch fee structure

Tags: vertex-ai-search

Sorry if this is the wrong place to ask this question.
Thanks for the feedback. I have revised the question.

I would like to know more about EnterpriseSearch's "Data Index Pricing" pricing structure and how it works.

I have read the documentation and am aware that the "data indexing pricing" is only for "advanced website indexing" if "advanced website indexing" is enabled, but otherwise I am not charged only for the amount of search queries?

Also, the billing information for "Generative AI App Builder - Enterprise Search" can be found in the billing report, but is there any place on the Google console where I can check the amount of data currently being used?

https://cloud.google.com/generative-ai-app-builder/pricing

https://cloud.google.com/generative-ai-app-builder/docs/about-advanced-features

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For clarification on website indexing (this is not currently documented, but it will be soon), Advanced Website indexing is charged as 500kb/page. There is work being done to make it easier to estimate the total cost of indexing.